# Bijection Cancellation rule for cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A$, $B$ and $C$ are sets, and that there is a bijection between $C \times A$ and $C \times B$. Is there necessarily a bijection between $A$ and $B$?

I know this should work for finite sets - you can use a size argument to demonstrate $A$ and $B$ have the same size, so there's a bijection between them. And I know that this works the other way around - if there's a bijection between $A$ and $B$, then for any set $C$ there's a bijection between $C \times A$ and $C \times B$. But is this true in general?

Comment: It is trivially not true if $C = \varnothing$. For the case when $C$ is non-empty and finite, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605779.pdf) shows the result to be true. (It proves it in the case that $|C| = 3$ but the technique can generalised for any (non-empty) finite $C$.)

Comment: This paper has nothing to do with the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without AC, there is a bijection from  $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbf{2}$ to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbf{3}$ but no bijection from $\mathbf2$ to $\mathbf3$ where $\mathbf{n}$ denotes the set of size $n$.

Comment: Yes, no need for AC ^^

Answer (score 0):

For infinite sets, if you accept the axiom of choice, you can show that $C\times A$ is in bijection with $C$ whenever $C$ is "bigger" than $A$.

So, if $C$ is bigger than both $A$ and $B$, there doesn't have to be a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Right, so for example if $C$ was $\mathbb{N}$, you could have $A = \{0, 1\}$ and $B = \{0, 1, 2\}$. Then you can set up a bijection from $C \times A$ to $C$, and from $C \times B$ to $C$, and hence from $C \times A$ to $C \times B$ - but of course there's no bijection between $A$ and $B$